# Cannot get MVC 5 Attribute Routing to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an MVC5 application with C# back-end. I am attempting to get change `/Controller/Action?parameter=value` show as `/Controller/Action/Value`.

Currently I have an action link on a page setup in hopes to be able to view the user's profile info:

```
@{ var test = new RouteValueDictionary {{"username", "testman"}}; }

  <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="border-right:1px solid #EEE; min-height: 250px;">
        Sidebar 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Test","Home",test)">test link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="border-left:1px solid #EEE; min-height: 250px;">
        Sidebar 2
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Action:

```
[RequireRequestValue(new[] { "username" })]
[Route("Test/{username}")]
public ActionResult Test(string username)
{
    var route = RouteData.Route;
    try
    {
        ViewBag.Page = 9;
        ViewBag.Title = "Testing";
        ViewBag.Message = username;

        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var error = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "Home", "Test");
        ViewBag.errorMessage = ex.Message;

        return View("Error", error);
    }
}
```

I have added `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` to my `RouteConfig.cs` file.

If I do not add the `[Route("Test/{username}")]` Attribute to my action, the link renders like this: `Home/Test?username=testman`. If I add the Attribute the link renders to my liking: `Home/Test/testman`.

Unfortunately, I get this server 500 error when I click on the link, and this is where I have been stuck:

```
No matching action was found on controller '<project>.Controllers.HomeController'.
This can happen when a controller uses RouteAttribute for routing, but no action on 
that controller matches the request.
```

For fun I even tried creating an explicit ActionResult to see if I could get something different, but no luck there.

I am obviously missing something...can anyone help me get on the right track?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `RequireRequestValue` Attribute? That is telling your route that it must have a Request Value (`?username=`)  present in the URL.  Your attribute routing solution doesn't provide it, so the route can't be matched.

Comment: Yikes that was it. I am surprised at myself for not trying that out in the first place. Thanks a million; a second pair of eyes is so useful!